# Extract string between xml tags in android without parsing the xml

Tags: java, android, regex, string, split

I have a very simple XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://icacec.com/">TRUE,Hrithik Sharma,201301-11</string>
```

Now, I want to extract only **TRUE**, **Hrithik Sharma**, **201301-11** in **3 separate variables**.

I could split the string based on the **","** like this:

```
String[] parts = responseBody.split(",");
String response_auth = parts[0];
String user_name = parts[1];    
String user_number=parts[2];
```

But the problem which I am facing is that, the Strings are not getting extracted independently. To be more precise, without the XML tags. How should I achieve that?

Comment: Strip the tags first?

Comment: use `indexOf` and `substring` functions for parsing current string to set test

Comment: substring might not be used as the content between the tags might vary

Comment: Any help with the code will be of great help!

Comment: @kittu88 : why sub string method not work? try this way : first extract indexof `com/">` substring and indexof `</s` substring then use substring method to extract final string

Comment: how to use indexof com/"> substring and indexof </s substring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could solve this simple case, but without parsing what are you going to do with other conditions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String raw = "<string xmlns=\"http://icacec.com/\">TRUE,Hrithik Sharma,201301-11</string>";
    raw = raw.substring(0, raw.lastIndexOf("<"));
    raw = raw.substring(raw.lastIndexOf(">") + 1, raw.length());
    String [] contents = raw.split(",");
    for (String txt : contents)
        System.out.println(txt);
}
```

Comment: undoubtedly,this is the solution to all kinds of xml data.. what i gave was for only that particular string

Answer (score 1):

This is highly discouraged unless you actually know what you are getting in XML

responseBody:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://icacec.com/">TRUE,Hrithik Sharma,201301-11</string>
```

code:

```
String[] parts = responseBody.split(">");
String tagsFirst= parts[0];
String usefull = parts[2];    

String[] actualBody = usefull.split("<");

String content = actualBody[0];
String[] contentParts=content.split(",");
//now you can have the three parts:
String truefalse=contentParts[0];
String name=contentParts[1];
String date=contentParts[2];
```

Comment: String truefalse=content[0]; giving an error, it says, The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

Comment: which string are you taking? the one i mentioned??..set breakpoint over content and debug and tell me what your getting in actualBody array

Comment: @Nezam: OP is right. `content` is a `String`, but you using array indexing `[]` to access it.

Comment: @nhahtdh my bad i didnt notice the error.. sigh i was the first one to answer...may be hastily though :smile:

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex -

```
"<string xmlns=\"http://icacec.com/\">(.+),(.+),(.+)</string>"
```

Capture groups 1, 2, and 3 will contain your three items, i.e.:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<string xmlns=\"http://icacec.com/\">(.+),(.+),(.+)</string>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<string xmlns=\"http://icacec.com/\">TRUE,Hrithik Sharma,201301-11</string>");

if(matcher.matches())
{
    System.out.println("Bool: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Name: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("Date: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to split like:

```
String[] strTemp = strXMLOutput.split("<TagName>");
strTemp = strTemp[1].split("</TagName>");
String strValue = strTemp[0]
```

100% it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String responseBody = null;
        String inputString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><string xmlns=\"http://icacec.com/\">TRUE,Hrithik Sharma,201301-11</string>";
        String regex = "<string[^>]*>(.+?)</string\\s*>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            responseBody = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }

        String[] splits = responseBody.split(",");
        System.out.println(splits[0]);/*prints TRUE*/
        System.out.println(splits[1]);/*prints Hrithik Sharma*/
        System.out.println(splits[2]);/*201301-11*/

    }

}
```