# how to get value from xml tag in android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have made a parser,in that i am getting all the values of that xml tag,But i want to get some values which are inside tag as an argument,I dont know how to get it from tags,The sample xml is as below:
**sample.xml**

```
  <ChargeableRateInfo averageBaseRate="226.7" averageRate="192.69" 
commissionableUsdTotal="192.69" currencyCode="USD" maxNightlyRate="192.69" 
nightlyRateTotal="192.69" surchargeTotal="46.8" total="239.49">
<NightlyRatesPerRoom size="1"><NightlyRate baseRate="226.7" 
rate="192.69" promo="true"/></NightlyRatesPerRoom>
```

,I want to get value of "averageRate","nightlyRateTotal","total",But I have no idea how to get that data?My parser is as below:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done) {
                tagName = parser.getName();

                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equals(ITEM)) {
                        rssFeed = new RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult();

                    }

                    if (tagName.equals(DESCRIPTION)) {
                        name = parser.nextText().toString();
                        hotel_name_list.add(name);
                        System.out
                                .println(":::::::::::::::::DescriptionL:lLLLLLLLLLL"
                                        + name);
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(OFFER)) {
                        offer = parser.nextText().toString();
                        hotel_offer_list.add(offer);
                        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::Offer" + offer);
                    }

                    if (tagName.equals(HOTEL_IMG)) {
                        thumbNailUrl = parser.nextText().toString();
                        hotel_image_list.add(thumbNailUrl);
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(HOTEL_LOCATION)) {
                        locationDescription = parser.nextText().toString();
                        hotel_lOCATION_DESC.add(locationDescription);
                        System.out
                                .println("::::::::;Location deccription:::::::::::;;"
                                        + locationDescription);
                    }

                    if (tagName.equals(HOTEL_RATE_IMG)) {
                        tripAdvisorRatingUrl = parser.nextText().toString();
                    }

                    if (tagName.equals(HOTEL_PRICE)) {
                        lowRate = parser.nextText().toString();
                    }

                    if (tagName.equals(HOTEL_RATING)) {
                        hotelRating = parser.nextText().toString();
                        hotel_rate_list.add(hotelRating);
                    }

                    if (tagName.equals(HOTEL_ADDRESS)) {
                        address1 = parser.nextText().toString();
                        hotel_address_list.add(address1);
                        System.out
                                .println(":::::::::::::hotel address:::::::::::"
                                        + address1);
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(DESTINATION_ID)) {
                        destinationId = parser.nextText().toString();
                        dest_id_list.add(destinationId);
                        System.out
                                .println("*********Here Is DestinationID:************"
                                        + destinationId);
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(CITY)) {
                        city = parser.nextText().toString();
                        city_list.add(city);
                        System.out.println("*********Here Is City:************"
                                + city);
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(HOTEL_ID)) {
                        hotelId = parser.nextText().toString();
                        hotel_id_list.add(hotelId);
                        System.out
                                .println("*********Here Is HotelID:************"
                                        + hotelId);
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(LATITUDE)) {
                        latitude = parser.nextText().toString();
                        latitude_list.add(latitude);
                        System.out
                                .println("*********Here Is Latitude:************"
                                        + hotelId);
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(LONGITUDE)) {
                        longitude = parser.nextText().toString();
                        longitude_list.add(longitude);
                        System.out
                                .println("*********Here Is Longitude:************"
                                        + hotelId);
                    }

                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equals(CHANNEL)) {
                        done = true;
                    } else if (tagName.equals(ITEM)) {

                        rssFeed = new RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult(name,
                                thumbNailUrl, tripAdvisorRatingUrl,
                                hotelRating, locationDescription, lowRate,
                                destinationId, city, hotelId, latitude,
                                longitude, offer);
                        rssFeedList.add(rssFeed);

                    }

                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rssFeedList;

    }
```

Comment: Are you parsing correctly? What's the value of CITY, HOTEL_ID and all?

Comment: @Tushar-Hello tushar,Thank you for response,Yes i am getting all the values correctly,But just want to know how to get values of xml arguments inside tags.

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15401895/3531756) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...  `parser.getAttributeValue(null, "averageRate");`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [DOM Parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) instead.

**Example**:

```
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(YOUR_XML);
 String averageBaseRate= doc.getElementsByTagName("ChargeableRateInfo ").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("averageBaseRate").getNodeValue();
 String averageRate= doc.getElementsByTagName("ChargeableRateInfo ").item(1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("averageRate").getNodeValue();
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

TAG_ITEM = "ChargeableRateInfo";

```
 XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput(new StringReader ("your_xml/"));
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
      if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
          System.out.println("Start document");
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          System.out.println("End document");
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
          System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());

// For Attribute 
String tag = parser.getName();
    if (TAG_ITEM.equals(tag)) {

        Log.d(LOG_NAME, parser.getAttributeValue(null, "averageBaseRate"); );


        Log.d(LOG_NAME, parser.getAttributeValue(null, "averageRate"); );


        Log.d(LOG_NAME, parser.getAttributeValue(null, "commissionableUsdTotal"); );


        Log.d(LOG_NAME, parser.getAttributeValue(null, "currencyCode"); );
    }   


      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
          System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
          System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
      }
      eventType = xpp.next();
     }
```